# How do I pull the oid organization id value out of the hidden field and populate it later using JavaScript

Tags: web2lead

How do I pull the oid organization id value out of the hidden field and populate it later using JavaScript. I need an example if possible, that I can implement on my Web-to-Lead form..please!

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Sharee. Have you examined your generated web-to-lead form to even look for it? Please take the time to visit [Help] and take our [Tour] to better understand how this forum works, including [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). We want your experience here to be a positive one where you'll be able to receive the answers you need and contribute to the community if you choose to.

Answer (score 1):

If your oid is already in the wild (e.g. you've posted a form and someone's already started spamming you), changing the form now will have no effect. They'll keep spamming you. The easiest way to stop this spam is to implement a hidden field value and write a validation rule that requires the field value to be present when the lead source is a certain value (e.g. Lead Source is web, Anti-Spam is Yes). It doesn't have to be complicated, any type of validation will do.

If you haven't exposed your oid yet, don't. Instead, have the web to lead form post back to your server, and have your server submit the data (along with the oid) to salesforce, or even better, consider using the API, which doesn't have the 500 leads per day limit (assuming, of course, you're on EE or have API enabled).